# Azure Batch default application package version

Tags: azure-batch

According to the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-application-packages), in Azure Batch without the version specified the default version of an application will be deployed.

In my Azure Batch Account I have uploaded an application "MyApp" and set the default version, lets say version "1.0".

When I create a new Pool (in .NET) if I set the ApplicationPackageReferences omitting the version, i.e:

```
 myCloudPool.ApplicationPackageReferences = new List<ApplicationPackageReference>
 {
     new ApplicationPackageReference 
     {
        ApplicationId = "MyApp"
     }
 };
```

The nodes will get the status "Unusable".

If I do the same, but at task level, then the default application is deployed successfully to the node.

Why is that?

Comment: Hiya, Cool, so what you mentioned above seems like this is happening at the pool level, this can only happen if there is a node error, can you check the error summary and see what is the error details appearing. I might be able to help you out. `:)`

Comment: I am taking a look and might build a small case around this and dig deeper, in the mean time, I would recommend using the version at the pool level OR if the task level with default version supports the scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you Olandese, I came across this specific case only in the case for default version at pool level and the fix is under its way, I will keep you posted when it will get released.

In the mean time there are few options or at pool level you can do so by using the `version` parameter.

- Task level packages with default, which you are already mentioned above.
- Use of the version parameter to pass the default version.

` 
Sample:

```
 new List< ApplicationPackageReference >

{
     new ApplicationPackageReference(appID, version: appVersion),
},
```

`

Thanks for your patience, apologies for the inconvenience, will update you once the release is out.

**Further addition: If you have faster changing default version**

I would do it this way: (With `appId` as constant and the `version` as the dynamic version)

- By doing this your code pretty much guarantees that node will go and grab the specified version mentioned if its there. Hope this helps.

`

```
new List<ApplicationPackageReference> 
    {
         new ApplicationPackageReference(appID, version: appVersion),
    },
```

Comment: Thank you Tats_innit!
I'm experiencing a new "issue": if I upload a new version of the package, let's say 1.1 and mark it as default, if I run the task again (without providing the version) the new version is not downloaded to the node.

Comment: No probs @Olandese thanks to you! `:)`  I think I might know whats happening, how quick are you changing the `default version`? , if the default value is changing too often and too soon, then your design should be using the non `defaultversion` upgrade, i.e. : `appId` and `version` passed together: which will guarantee the specific version gets downloaded if not there. I will update more detail in above post, but will be good that in your design how soon you are flicking between default version.

Comment: thank you again, indeed, more documentation about that will be fine :)

Comment: is there some place where I can give more feedback?

Comment: I reckon there is a feature request page, `:)` lemme find it for you. What exactly does it relates to? et. al.

Comment: it's about JobPreparationTask and JobReleaseTasks. I only need the JobReleaseTaks, but I MUST create also a JobPreparationTask, otherwise it doesn't work, which (for me) is quiet odd. So I added a JobPreparationTasks which just "echos" something. 
I am using the C# SDK (Azure.Batch, 8.0.0)

Comment: Awesome!! @Olandese I found it for you `:)` yeah that will be great, we strive in making things awesome. Here is the link for you: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/269742-azure-batch - Thanks!

Comment: Done: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/269742-batch/suggestions/32312944-make-jobpreparationtask-and-jobreleasetasks-indepe

Comment: @Olandese nice!